# Mongo mapping converter not being invoked

Tags: spring, mongodb, converters

I have a Mongo mapping converter configured in spring XML as follows :

```
<mongo:mapping-converter>
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.pqbook.marc.mongo.converters.MarcRecordMongoReaderConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

I have a Mongo collection from where the field of type 'Record' is to be read and converted to my custom POJO type 'MyRecord'.
My converter class looks like this :

```
@Component
public class MarcRecordMongoReaderConverter implements Converter<Record, MyRecord> {

@Override
public MyRecord convert(Record source) {
    // the conversion code
    // this method returns an object of type 'MyRecord'
}
```

}

Do I need to register this converter in a different way? At which point will this converter be invoked? Is there something that am missing to include?

Comment: How is your spring component scan set up ?

Comment: In the context:component-scan I have included the package of the converter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration should look similar to this. You have to register the converter with mongo template.

```
<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="test" />

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter" base-package="com.pqbook.marc.mongo">
        <mongo:custom-converters>
            <mongo:converter>
                <bean class="com.pqbook.marc.mongo.converters.MarcRecordMongoReaderConverter" />
            </mongo:converter>
        </mongo:custom-converters>
    </mongo:mapping-converter>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I did not have the base-package in the mongo:mapping-converter earlier.